# how to implement re-authorization for linkedin

Tags: php, codeigniter, linkedin-api

I want to protect specific pages on my website by prompting the user to re-enter their password even if they are already logged in through linkedin.

Just like facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication), is there any option to do it for linkedin? I couldn't find anything in the api docs.